# ¿ como puedo poner un distinct al resultado de un select que contiene otro distinct?

Tags: mysql, sql

esta consulta me arroja datos repetidos, y quiero ponerle un distinct al resultado de la misma. ayudenme por favor,gracias de antemano.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT c.*, IF (c.code = 'FF', "INICIO" , "-") AS PARTIDA,
    IF(re.code_enlace = 'FF', CONCAT("INVITADO DE ", r.code_enlace),
    CONCAT("INVITADO DE", c.code)) AS INVITADO_POR FROM clientes c,
    relacion r, relacion re WHERE r.code_enlace = 'FF' AND ((c.code =
    r.code OR c.code = 'FF') OR (re.code_enlace = r.code AND c.code =
    re.code)) ORDER BY PARTIDA DESC, INVITADO_POR ;
```

Comment: Ya probaste una consulta sobre esta? Es decir; SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (SELEC DISTINCT c.* ..... )

Comment: si,me sale este error : Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM (SELEC DISTINCT c.* ..... ) as t1

Comment: si le salen resultados repetidos, hacer un distinct de algo que ya hace distinct no le va a traer menos resultados. para ayudarte deberiamos ver los datos de entrada y tambien como queres que quede la salida y como queda actualmente.